# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^ (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create and run some JS code by creating a script tag and inserting the code via the innerHtml property, but I keep getting the following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^ (anonymous function) (line
>   50)

Line 50 is where I append the tag to the body.

```
body.appendChild(krux);
```

Can someone review my code and let me know if they can spot any errors? I'm using this technique with a lot of other 3rd party tags and haven't had any issues with it until now.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <title>Example Page</title>
</head>

<script>
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
   var krux = ""+
           "window.Krux || ((Krux=function(){Krux.q.push(arguments);}).q=[]);"+
           "(function(){"+
           "  function retrieve(n){"+
           "      var m, k='kx'+n;"+
           "      if (window.localStorage) {"+
           "          return  window.localStorage[k]  ||  '';"+
           "      }   else    if  (navigator.cookieEnabled)   {"+
           "          m   =   document.cookie.match(k+'=([^;]*)');"+
           "          return  (m  &&  unescape(m[1])) ||  '';"+
           "      }   else    {"+
           "          return  '';"+
           "      }"+
           "  }"+
           ""+
           "  Krux.user     = retrieve('user');"+
           "  Krux.segments = retrieve('segs') ? retrieve('segs').split(',') : [];"+
           ""+
           "  var dfpp    =   [];"+
           "  if  (Krux.user) {"+
           "      dfpp.push('khost='  +   encodeURIComponent(location.hostname));"+
           "      dfpp.push('kuid='   +   Krux.user);"+
           "  }"+
           "  for (var i = 0; i < Krux.segments.length; i++) {"+
           "      dfpp.push('ksg=' + Krux.segments[i]);"+
           "  }"+
           "  Krux.dfppKeyValues = dfpp.length ? dfpp.join(';') + ';' : '';"+
           "})();"+
           ""+
           "(function(){"+
           "    var k=document.createElement('script');k.type='text/javascript';k.async=true;"+
           "    var m,src=(m=location.href.match(/\bkxsrc=([^&]+)/))&&decodeURIComponent(m[1]);"+
           "    k.src = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?krxd\.net(:\d{1,5})?\//i.test(src) ? src : src === 'disable' ? '' : "+
           "        (location.protocol==='https:'?'https:':'http:')+'//cdn.krxd.net/controltag?confid=IkIevuhg';"+
           "    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(k,s);"+
           "}());";

   var script       = document.createElement("script");
   script.type      = "text/javascript";
   script.innerHTML = krux;
   body.appendChild(script);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you do this and not just run the script?

Comment: Your regex isn't properly escaped in your string literal (`"    k.src = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)`). But the solution isn't to escape it but to stop writing javascript code in a javascript string literal.

Comment: @qwertynl is right. This is too complicated to debug.

Comment: @dystroy the app I'm working on serves these tags (and many others) dynamically to many sites that our hosting our widgets. We didn't want to lose control of the tags in case we need to make changes so this was the only way I could see it working. Your answer was technically correct so if you want you can add that as your answer I will give you credit for it. Thanks.

Comment: There (amazingly) doesn't seem to be any error in your JS. Are you sure you are doing `body.appendChild(script)` and not `body.appendChild(krux)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn't properly escaped in your string literal (`" k.src = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)`) : you must replace the `\` with `\\`.

But the right solution isn't to escape it but to stop writing javascript code in a javascript string literal. There are many ways to dynamically insert a script in a page, for example using AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

The error comes from the HUGE string you're trying to parse as javascript, the errors are in there.

Comment: *"you need to fix it, take the line out completely and your error should be gone."*. No. He need to completely change the design of his application. Having js code in a big string literal isn't maintainable, even when fixed.

Comment: @dystroy I know that, that's why I do not do it.